# Detecting the end of navigation in Waze or Google Maps for mobile

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I want my mobile app to be triggered by the "end-of-navigation" in either Waze or the Google Maps app. In it's simplest form, I would like my app to do something when the user gets the "You've arrived at your destination" notification from the navigation app.

I realize, in Android at least, that I can start the navigation (either in Waze, or Google Maps app) by creating an intent. Then, I can run my own proximity sensor in my app to wait for the user to arrive. However, I wanted something far cleaner - a situation where all that is required from the user is to have my app working in the background and then for this app to able to respond to the event of arrival directly.

Solutions either in iOS or Android are very welcome. Hacky solutions are also very welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution will be to create a GeoFence just before the intent for navigation is started. You can listen to Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER event using an intent service running in background. When this event happens you can do what ever task you need to do from the service class. This same principle can be implemented in ios also: 
Here is a tutorial for implementing Geofence in ios http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift and in android http://paulusworld.com/technical/android-geofences

Comment: Yup, mentioned this option in the question. The main drawback here is that one has to know the destination a priori, rather than just "listening" for an "arrived" event and then behaving accordingly. The latter is what I'm looking for and can be a way to provide some pretty cool extra functionality on top of existing navigation apps (check-ins, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

A super hacky thing you could do (almost don't want to post this) would be to use the NotificationListenerService and keep an eye out for the notifications from google maps or waze.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#nestedclasses

I think it should be for public to use as long as you have the permission.

You're going to have to think of something smart for languages, maybe reading resources from the google maps / waze apps to ensure you don't miss notifications that are not in English.

This may be viable for iOS as well: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html I don't have personal experience with the watch Apis for iOS so you'll have to dig around there yourself.

Comment: Cool. Gimme a couple of days to give this a try and post findings. Thanks

Comment: this is an interesting idea, and i'm glad you did post it ! some pretty big apps got started on hacks a lot worse than this i think...

Comment: Has anyone implemented this and can report on stability?

Comment: @Bjorn, actually I didn't yet... other things got in the way, but if you do and it works it'd be great if you could post back your success / failure.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution here is to poll the active activities (foreground ones) each X seconds and act from there. You can do it with a service and alarm.

You can do it in the following ways:

Check current running processes:

```
 ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes) {
       if (processName.equals(process.processName)) {
           // do your thing
       }
    }
```

OR (less preferred) check the current foreground application:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity
                .getPackageName();
```

Comment: This is a hack too, down voted until post is updated with more correct info.

Comment: Removed down vote but I have a question, from looking at the Apis available for the running processes how is this going to determine if the user has arrived at their destination or not? Only thing I can think of is to rely on that both apps show a different activity upon arrival, which I'm not convinced they do.

Comment: You cannot be sure 100% but you can assume...  If user is navigating to some place then the app process must be up and the activity probably should be in front. There are certain situation when the process is up but activity not in front - this can happen when the user got a phone call for example. You will have to think about it a adjust your logic so that it will fit a real life scenario.

Comment: That's not really an answer then. The activity can be on top regardless of if we are currently navigating or not. Which means that your only possible solution is not a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS i am not sure you will get a call back from google or Waze. best way is to use `startMonitoringForRegion`. if you enter region(destination) your app will get a call back. if your app is not running OS will launch your application. hope this will help