# Waze maps intent call back in Android

Tags: android, maps, waze

I'm using the below code to launch Waze maps. Now  my app want to get a callback whenever the Waze map has been loaded? Is there any direct call backs available? I googled but no luck. 
Any hack or any way can I achieve this?

```
String url = "waze://?q="+destination+ "&navigate=yes";
Intent intentWaze = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
intentWaze.setPackage("com.waze");
mContext.startActivity(intentWaze);
```

Any Links or code will be helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no available broadcast recievers to know whether waze has been loaded or not,

You can use only use `resolveActivity` method to know wheter waze intent is available or not:

```java
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intentWaze.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intentWaze);
} else {
   // No Intent available to handle action
}
```

Comment: Hi Saeed thanks for your quick reply. I'm expecting not just start of the waze activity, something from waze like onMapsLoaded once the location has been set. sorry if my question was not clear

Comment: @Manju You mean you want to get a callback in your app whenever the Waze map has been loaded?

Comment: Yes that is what exactly I want.

Comment: you mean to say we cant achieve this. Is there any hack like thing listening to some notifications like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511169/detecting-the-end-of-navigation-in-waze-or-google-maps-for-mobile. But this is for end of route

Comment: @Manju no, you can't